# SQLite UPDATE now working or I have done wrong

Tags: sqlite

Current table questions:

```
rowid: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
id:    3 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 10
```

Trying to achieve the following:

```
rowid: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

id:    1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

I have tried many different variations of SQL without success, this is the latest I am testing:

> UPDATE questions SET id = rowid;

Can someone please suggest how I solve this as I have googled and cannot find the solution?

Comment: Your statement is correct.

Comment: See this: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that your question completely encompasses all aspects of the issue.

In theory to have a table (the before table) where `SELECT rowid, id` results in

```
rowid: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
id:    3 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 10
```

The **id** column must not be an alias of the **rowid** column (otherwise the values would be identical)

However, if the id column is an alias of the **rowid** column, the both columns would be the same so the before table above would not be as above.

As an example using :-

```
--<<<<<<<<<< WORKS >>>>>>>>>>
-- as ID is not an alias of the rowid column update changes id column
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS questionsv3;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questionsv3 (ID INTEGER);
INSERT INTO questionsv3 VALUES (3),(4),(7),(9),(10);
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv3;
UPDATE questionsv3 SET id = rowid;
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv3;
```

results in the expected result as per :-

*First Select (before update)* :-

[image]

*Second Select (after update)*

[image]

## Other potential causes

1. **rowid** is not in fact the **rowid** as per SQLITE, but a conceptual idea that it should be 1,2,3 ...... (in which case using VACUUM, if there is no alias to the rowid, may result in the desired re-numbering of the rowid column, which if followed by the update may then result in the id being re-sequenced).
2. That the update is done within a transaction that hasn't been committed and is rolled back.

You may wish to consider the following permutations of different table creations (see comments) :-

```
-- as ID is an alias of rowid, then rowid is set according to ID so update does nothing
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS questionsv1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questionsv1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO questionsv1 VALUES (3),(4),(7),(9),(10);
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv1;
UPDATE questionsv1 SET id = rowid;
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv1;

-- as ID is an alias of the rowid column, then rowid is set according to the ID so update does nothing
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS questionsv2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questionsv2 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);
INSERT INTO questionsv2 VALUES (3),(4),(7),(9),(10);
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv2;
UPDATE questionsv2 SET id = rowid;
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv2;

--<<<<<<<<<< WORKS >>>>>>>>>>
-- as ID is not an alias of the rowid column update changes id column
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS questionsv3;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questionsv3 (ID INTEGER);
INSERT INTO questionsv3 VALUES (3),(4),(7),(9),(10);
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv3;
UPDATE questionsv3 SET id = rowid;
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv3;

--<<<<<<<<<< WORKS >>>>>>>>>>
-- as ID is not an alias of rowid the ID column is updated accordingly
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS questionsv4;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questionsv4 (ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY); -- not an alias of rowid
INSERT INTO questionsv4 VALUES (3),(4),(7),(9),(10);
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv4;
UPDATE questionsv4 SET id = rowid;
SELECT rowid, id FROM questionsv4;

--<<<<<<<<<< FAILS >>>>>>>>>>
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS questionsv13;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questionsv13 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) WITHOUT ROWID;
INSERT INTO questionsv13 VALUES (3),(4),(7),(9),(10);
SELECT id FROM questionsv13;
UPDATE questionsv13 SET id = rowid; -- would fail no such column
SELECT id FROM questionsv13;
```